# Why relative import so restrict?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module, relative-path

With directory:

```
app/
    sub1/
        __init__.py
        module1.py
    sub2/
        __init__.py
        test.py
```

what I imagine import a module to do is:

1. create a scope(or thread?)
2. run module.py in that scope

`from ..sub import module1` is invalid with top-level at `test.py`

but `open('../sub1/module1.py', 'r')` works !!

So it's readable, but not importable.

Start with something similar to `import moudule as *`

```py
exec(open('../sub1/module1.py', 'r').read())
```

Do further by execute this script in a sepcific scope, and name that scope.

class would provide a scope, also calling class variables is similar to calling module variables.

`import module1 as cus`

```py
class Module:
    exec(open('../sub1/module1.py', 'r').read(), locals(), locals())
cus = Mudule()
cus.function_inside_module1()
```

function `exec(object[, globals[, locals]])` run `object` under `globals` scope, and store variables into `locals`. (I guess)

Since argument `globals` and `locals` are both `locals()` of class `Module`, it's like what i imagine import to do.

If this work properly, module under module can be writen as nested class i guess.

What kind of problems will this odd importing cause?

If not, why a file is readable but not importable(with top-level restriction)?

**Edit**

@user2357112 sorry I don't knew how to write multiline comment:

would this gives the behavior you asked for loading parent package?

```py
class sub1:
    exec(open('../sub1/__init__.py', 'r').read(), locals(), locals())
    class Module:
        exec(open('../sub1/module1.py', 'r').read(), locals(), locals())
cus = sub1.Module()
del sub1
```

Comment: Relative imports are not a directory traversal mechanism.

Comment: How are you running the program? Is it `python3 test.py`? What directory are you in?

Comment: @user2357112 - I don't understand. For file based modules, it is a directory traversal.

Comment: @tdelaney yes, in test.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative imports are not a directory traversal mechanism. `from ..a import b` does not mean "go up a directory, enter the `a` directory, and load `b.py`". It means "import the `b` member of the `a` submodule of the current package's *parent package*". This usually looks a lot like what the directory traversal would do, but it is not the same, especially for cases involving namespace packages, custom module loaders, or `sys.modules` manipulation.

`sub2` has no parent package. Trying to refer to a nonexistent parent package is an error. Also, if you ran `test.py` directly by file name, `sub2` is not even considered a package at all.

Comment: tysm, i will try to figure out what those" namespace packages, custom module loader ..." are.